# How to remove .php extension with .htaccess after installing Laravel 4 on godaddy?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, shared-hosting

I have my Laravel 4 core files uploaded in a folder call "laravel" and uploaded the contents from public folder to www folder.

After some configuration with the path, the webpage was able to load but with a ".php" extension to it.

Any ways I can fix it with the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325314/extensionless-url-trailing-slash-redirect) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534132/how-can-i-make-all-my-urls-extensionless-without-trailing-slash-and-redirect-t).

Here's a sample .htaccess file that can handle PHP scripts without the trailing .php extension:

```
RewriteEngine on

#unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

#redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```