# How do I create clean URLs in PHP with proper redirect in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've cut and pasted so many .htaccess files my fingers are turning blue. The last few solutions I tried, redirected all of my links to index.php and I don’t want that. Since I don’t really understand what I’m doing, I can’t figure out how to fix this. I’m a web designer, not a programmer, but I prefer the clean URLs. So, I need to do the following:

1. Redirect www and http to https;
2. Make all URLs extensionless, without trailing slash;
3. Redirect each .php and trailing slash to the clean URL--I have multiple PHP files, so I need a wildcard solution, not one for a specific page;
4. I also display data pulled from a database on two different pages (view.php and edit.php). I'd like the URL to look like view/1 and edit/1 instead of view.php?id=1 and edit.php?id=1.

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

My host provides free SSL and told me to place the above code to redirect www and http to https, so I think I’m all set with #1. I now need to figure out how to implement/integrate #2, #3 and #4.

I have tried solutions at [How can I make all my urls extensionless, without trailing slash. And redirect the .php and trailing slash to none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534132/how-can-i-make-all-my-urls-extensionless-without-trailing-slash-and-redirect-t) and [How to redirect all my urls with no extension to end with .php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605184/how-to-redirect-all-my-urls-with-no-extension-to-end-with-php) and many others, but nothing gives me exactly what I need.

Comment: You might want to use a router in your PHP code. With the current configuration, your index.php file acts as an entry point to your app, and you can retrieve and parse the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] from there.
Attempting to create a website with clean urls using only mod_rewrite is an experience I had in the past and would never reiterate, because it is simply not maintainable. Plus, migrating to another webserver such as nginx would be simply impossible.
See something like https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router for an example.

Comment: First of all, what do your links look like? A common issue with pretty URLs is that the expectation is the wrong way around. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476.

Comment: In the few hours since I posted, I've gained a little more understanding. I now know I have to edit my document links (e.g., change "contact.php" to "contact", etc). The link you posted was helpful. But now, @SirDarius has me concerned about doing things this way. I'll look into routers as well. Again, though, not a programmer.

Comment: @SirDarius, as I stated in my post, I'm not a programmer. I'm afraid the routers link you provided isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It took me 10 hours, with a short break, but I think I figured it out. It certainly seems to work so far.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^account/content$ content.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^account/email-reset$ email-reset.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^account/pwd-reset$ pwd-reset.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^view/(\d+)$ view.php?qdetailsid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^edit/(\d+)$ edit.php?qdetailsid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^delete/(\d+)$ delete.php?qdetailsid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```